# Ключевое слово typedef в объявлениях

Tags: c++

Всем здрасти!
Скажите пожалуйста, зачем при объявлении переменных некоторые программисты используют ключевое слово typedef?
Пример:
typedef double itsdouble;

Answer (score 5):

Использование "синонимов" для простых типов может быть нужно для лучшего понимания кода. Скажем, вы можете создать такой псевдоним:

```
typedef unsigned int  size
```

и тем самым человеку, читающему код, будет легче понять, что переменные этого типа предназначены для храннения размера чего-нибудь, тогда как по переменной типа unsigned int этого так сразу не скажешь.  Также имеет смысл использовать typedef для упрощения чересчур запутанных определений. Согласитесь, гораздо лучше воспринимать такое:

```
typedef void (*func)();
```

и впоследствии использовать в коде уже **func**.

В случае со структурами typedef также может быть полезен вот для чего:

```
struct myStruct { } ;

typedef struct myStructTwo 
{ 
} mystructTwo;

main()
{
    // так нельзя
    myStruct  ms1;

    // нужно так:
    struct myStruct  ms2;

   // а здесь без struct
    mystructTwo ms4;
}
```

Comment: В дополнение: В старых версиях C++ без ключевого слова `auto` `typedef` был просто необходим, чтобы сократить длину конструкций типа

    for (std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> >::const_iterator it ... )

С подходящим `typedef` это выглядело несколько лучше:

    for (PossibleTypos::const_iterator...)

Answer (score 3):

Создание алиаса наименования типа. Коротко и неточно.

Например, при объявлении

```
typedef unsigned long ulong
```

Можно не писать *unsigned long*, а ограничиться *ulong*.

Comment: Не всегда. IMHO в stdint.h можно найти короткие и точные typedef-ы для целых разного размера.

Comment: Коротко и не точно - это про мое описание =)

Comment: Про синонимы я знал, за структуры - спасибо, но я имел в виду следующее: во многих кодах вижу, что программеры пишут "typedef int itsA", и далее по коду везде используют "itsA". Так для чего же использовали typedef, если и так все определилось и без него будет работать?

Comment: @BESSONoff, некоторые люди считают, что если *название* типа совпадает с названием какой-то группы объектов в *предметной области* (другими словами имеет смысл в ней), то это упрощает программирование.

IMHO по отношению к примитивным типам (да и по большей части к структурам) это неверно. При чтении такого кода плохо ощущается его связь с реальностью (железом и системой). Предметнику *писать* может и легче, а вот отлаживать такой чужой код сложно (много времени тратиться на "вхождение в тему").

А вообще, не забывайте, программы нужно писать для других людей (читателей).